# Inserção no Mysql com radio button + <option> + input

Tags: php, mysql

Como inserir no banco de dados o valor do `<input>` conforme o radio button for selecionado?
Segue em anexo um modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$funcionario = $this->funcionario->get_all_funcionario();
    if($funcionario->num_rows > 0){
    $row = $funcionario->row();
    $atributosfuncionario = array('name' => 'xd', 'class' => 'funcionario', 'value' => $row->pessoa_id);
    echo form_radio($atributosfuncionario);
    echo form_label('Funcionário');
    echo form_input(array('name' => 'pessoa', 'class' => 'selects', 'disabled' => 'disabled'), set_value('pesssoa', $row->nome));
    }
    $atributoscidadao = array('name' => 'xd', 'class' => 'cidadao');
    echo form_radio($atributoscidadao);
    echo form_label('Cidadão');
    echo '<select name="pessoa" class="select">';
    $opcao = $this->funcionario->get_all_pessoa()->result();
    foreach($opcao as $linha){
    echo '<option value="'.$linha->id.'">'.$linha->nome.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Quando efetuo o cadastro, ele só está pegando o valor do `<option>` Mário Silva, ou qualquer outro valor do `<option>`. Por que não consigo pegar o valor no input text? marco o radio button, e mesmo assim continua! Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Cara, sua pergunta ficou meio evasiva. Você quer *puxar* o valor da `<option>` ao enviar o formulário e depois cadastrar no banco?

Comment: Os dados estão vindo do banco de dados, e vão ser inseridos no BD! Só coloquei OBS: só pra informar que os dados do option estão sendo exibidos dinamicamente, ou seja, pelo banco de dados!

Answer (score 1):

@user11545 independente da pessoa marcar ou vc pegar do banco vai ser inserido sempre o valor do input, select, checkbox que estiver marcado.

para pegar o valor vc envia seu formulário pra uma página desse jeito.

```
$nome1 = $_POST["nomedoinput"];
$nome2 = $_POST["nomedoinput"];
$nome3 = $_POST["nomedoinput"];
```

e insere no banco assim

```
INSERT INTO tabela_nome VALUES ($nome1,$nome2,$nome3,...);
```